# Google Apps script function does not work when implemented via a library

Tags: google-apps-script

I am right at the beginning of my Google Apps Script programming and I have a real problem that I hope some one can help me with. I spent all yesterday trying to solve this but I am going in circles.

I wrote a script that was bound to a Google Doc. From a custom menu I call a html form where I collect the necessary information.

```
function initiateInvoice() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('askQu.html')
    .setWidth(800)
    .setHeight(500);
  DocumentApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Daten Eingabe');
}
```

This form has a „submit“ button and an "exit" button.

```
<input class="action" onclick="formSubmit()" type="button" value="Submit" />
<input onclick="google.script.host.close()" type="button" value="Exit" />
```

The script called when the "submit" button is pressed is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function formSubmit() {
    google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(document.forms[0]);
    google.script.host.close();
  }
</script>
```

The function getValuesFromForm then does the stuff that I need doing. And the html form is closed. The stuff that happens is a few calculations and then replacing place holders with text or numbers. I don't think this is relevant but can supply any code needed as required.

This all works exactly as I had hoped.

But now I have moved all the code and html in to an extra library (except the calling of the custom menu). The form still shows when called via the custom menu but the submit button in the form has no function any more. The "exit" button will still work. I have tried stripping everything out of the function that is called so that it does nothing nothing (to be sure it wasn't being called and getting hung up) but this does not help.

I guess that the javascript in the form is not working or not reaching my function  getValuesFromForm but I really have no idea where to look or what to do.

I really appreciate any help or tips that any one can give me. Thank you. 
Greetings from the Bavarian Alps.

Neill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`google.script.run` can't run a function from a library, only from a .gs file in the same project.

If you must have your logic code in a library, you will have to create functions in your local .gs file to call the relevant library functions, and these local functions you can invoke with `google.script.run`

Comment: Thank you for the clear and helpful answer. I should have asked  24 hours earlier and saved myself some grey hairs. Maybe this is documented some where but I could not find it - or it is documented in a way I didn't understand.

Comment: It is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#private_functions): `google.script` _is also unable to see functions within libraries_